# Firebase database rule - Check for initial child values

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

A user should only be created if he has the correct children with correct initial values.

The following code works but it prevents me to change the values like health after the user was created.

How can I check only for the initial child values?

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
            ".write": false,
                "users": {
            // Only allow writes in users
            ".write": true,
                "$user": {
                // Check if new user has the correct children
                ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['userID', 'deviceModel', 'health', 'age', 'playername', 'score', 'clickedby', 'timestamp'])
                    // Check if new user has a health of 10
                    && newData.child('health').val() == '10'
                    // Check if new user has an age of 0
                    && newData.child('age').val() == '0'
                    // Check if new user has a score of 0
                    && newData.child('score').val() == '0'
                    // Check if new user has a timestamp which is not a future value
                    && newData.child('timestamp').val() <= now"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update: The rules of Frank van Puffelen work perfectly**

**Here are my updated rules:**

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
            ".write": false,
                "users": {
            // Only allow writes in users
            ".write": true,
                "$user": {
                // Check if new user has the correct children
                ".validate": "data.exists() || (
                newData.hasChildren(['userID', 'deviceModel', 'health', 'age', 'playername', 'score', 'clickedby', 'timestamp'])
                    // Check if new user has a health of 10
                    && newData.child('health').val() == 10
                    // Check if new user has an age of 0
                    && newData.child('age').val() == 0
                    // Check if new user has a score of 0
                    && newData.child('score').val() == 0
                    // Check if new user has a timestamp which is not a future value
                    && newData.child('timestamp').val() <= now) "
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to check for new data, you can use `data.exist()`. For example:

```
".validate": "data.exists() || (
  newData.hasChildren(['userID', 'deviceModel', 'health', 'age', 'playername', 'score', 'clickedby', 'timestamp'])
    // Check if new user has a health of 10
    && newData.child('health').val() == '10'
    // Check if new user has an age of 0
    && newData.child('age').val() == '0'
    // Check if new user has a score of 0
    && newData.child('score').val() == '0'
    // Check if new user has a timestamp which is not a future value
    && newData.child('timestamp').val() <= now
 )"
```

Unrelated: I'd consider storing numeric values in numbers, instead of in string values as you do now. So that'd be `newData.child('health').val() == 10`, etc.

Btw: kudos on writing such beautiful security rules early on in development.

Comment: Thank you so much Frank! Your rules work perfectly. The only thing I had to do was to move the last ) before the last " like so: <= now) ". And also thank you for the tip to store the numeric values in numbers, instead of in string values. It was always not nice to use int.Parse in Unity :) I would love to show you my current multiplayer game project. Would you be interested to join my test on Firebase?